# Trouble with React/JS filter

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, filtering

I am trying to implement a filter function that is able to search in two separate JSON fields when a user types in a search bar. Searching the whole JSON returns errors and if I repeat this function, the two similar functions cancel each other out.

My current filter function:

```
let filteredOArt = origArt.filter((origAItem) => {
                return origAItem.authors.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())
            });
```

I want to be able to have the search look within the "authors" field as well as a "description" field.

Before the React render, I have this function listening to the state:

```
updateSearch(event) {
    this.setState({ search: event.target.value }) 
}
```

Then my search function is in an input field in the React return:

```
<h6>Search by author name: <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} /></h6>
```

Comment: can you please share your `origArt` content? that's really hard to say if the filter is working, if we don't see how the data is structured

Comment: It is set up like this:

 "articles": [
        {
            "authors": "Iaizzo PA, Pozos RS:",
            "description": "Exercise-induced amplitude modification of physiological action tremor of the ankle.",
            "publisher": "Journal of Applied Physiology 53: 1164-1170,",
            "date": "1982.",
            "journalID": "PMID: 7174409"
        },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak the function a bit like this

```
let filteredOArt = origArt.filter((origAItem) => {
       return (
(origAItem.authors.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())||

(origAItem.description.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())
       )
)
        });
```

Comment: Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly and kept the code easy to read!

Answer (score 1):

You actually can do a filter for both fields.

Given you have your searchValue and your array with the objects you could filter this way:

```
const filterByAuthorOrDescription = (searchValue, array) =>
  array.filter(
    item =>
      item.authors.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()) ||
      item.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
  );
```

```
const filtered = filterByAuthorOrDescription(this.state.search, articles);
```

`filtered` will now contain an array of objects that contain your searchValue in either description or authors that you can map through.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if the filter is positive for at least one field :

```
let filteredOArt = origArt.filter(origAItem => ['authors', 'description'].some(field => origAItem.[field].toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())))
```

Just iterate over the different field names you want to use.

`Some` will return `true` if any of the fields mentioned contains your string and avoid repetitions in your code.

Long syntax :

```
origArt.filter(origAItem => {
    return ['authors', 'description'].some(field => origAItem.[field].toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase()))
})
```